# Cross Site Forms LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap, forms-authentication

I am creating a website that uses LDAP forms authentication, this works fine. However, there is a pre-existing website that also uses LDAP forms authentication, that I would like to be able to access without having users enter user name and passwords again.

Is it possible to pass the LDAP "session authentication" from one website to another? I don't have the ability to change the pre-existing website.

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot change the existing application, it makes it hard.

1. A simple way that may work, is when a user logs in on your site, you could post the credentials to the external site login page at the same time. Its kind of lame, and may have issues with cross domain postbacks, session timeouts etc.
2. The other way you could do it, is if you create an asp.net proxy website. Basically it sits between the browser and the 2 websites. It collects the credentials and authenticates to both your site and the external one. When cookies come back from the two websites, you prefix them with different id, then pass them to the browser. I have built something like this before and it works well, ***BUT*** you will need to learn a lot about how HTTP works.
3. Or can you use some kind of pre-built proxy, like ISA/TMG?

Comment: Ok, 

So effectively I would be copying the cookie of the site I have created and uses LDAP forms authentication, and duping the pre-existing website into using a version of this cookie?

Comment: if you want to use the same cookie, then its like a single signon component, and i think you will need to modify the existing app. i think you will need to have two seperate cookies if you are attempting the 2nd option. each application exists standalone, and you build a proxy to make it "look" like they are the same